# Django form is throwing error: "takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)"

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm working on a basic event form created from a model, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
TypeError at /addlaundry/
addlaundry() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

I think it's because I'm not passing the argument through on views, but I can't find documented anywhere how to do this right, at least not written in a way I understand.

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^addlaundry/$', 'beacon.laundry.views.addlaundry'),
}
```

And the views itself:

```
# Create your views here.

from schedule.views import EventForm

def addlaundry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') #redirect after succesfully adding new delivery
    else:
     form = addlaundry()

    return render_to_response('newlaundry.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Do I indeed have my views wrongly structured, or am I missing something else? If there's documentation I need to read up on, I want to I just haven't found it but feel like I'm missing something basic.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: So basic, I am ashamed. Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
form = addlaundry()
```

You're calling your view function `addlaundry` which takes 1 required argument (`request`), but you're not passing it any arguments.

Of course, that's not the right way to construct a form, anyway. You'll want to take a look at the examples given in the [Django forms documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/#topics-forms-index) to see how to create and use forms in Django.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is called `addlaundry`, and it calls (presumably) something else called `addlaundry`. Rename one of them, or use the other `addlaundry` from inside its namespace.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
 form = addlaundry()
```

That's attempting to call the view itself! That's not what you want. You need to define a form class and call (instantiate) it here.

Answer (score 1):

views.py :

```
from schedule.forms import EventForm

def addlaundry(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EventForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = EventForm()

    return render_to_response('newlaundry.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

**That means :**

- using a forms.py file to define your forms
- initializing your form in a non post context (regular first page load), that will be passed to your template

Answer (score 1):

Also, in urls.py your view should not be a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
else:
 form = addlaundry()
```

Just as the exception says: The view function needs 1 argument, but you didn't supply any.